# How to change the permission to access the hadoop services?

Tags: hadoop, service

[image: **enter image description here**]

I have checked by changing the permissions of `start-all.sh` but it is showing as no file. How can I solve this error?

Comment: you have not changed your directory to hadoop/sbin to change the permission. Run `cd hadoop/sbin` command and try chmod. Note that to start hadoop services, you should run the command starting with `./` not `start-all.sh`. Except you have defined sbin folder in your PATH.

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one shell script that needs to be executable.

Try the following first

```
find $HOME/hadoop -name '*.sh' -exec chmod +x {} ;\
```

Also, `hadoop namenode` and `hadoop datanode` could be started individually.